# Docker don't run with proxy

Tags: docker, authentication, virtualbox, linux-mint

i need your help,

My docker don't run on my enterprise, I do not know what to do

```
kaue default # docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
9bb5a5d4561a: Pulling fs layer 
docker: error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/e3/e38bc07ac18ee64e6d59cf2eafcdddf9cec2364dfe129fe0af75f1b0194e0c96/data?verify=1528483070-KGbywXnskgTKu5B9AuTdFPQdYjs%3D: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
See 'docker run --help'
```

.

I have a Windows 7, and Authenticated proxy in my job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the proxy in your environment before running the docker run command...

set HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy_name_or_ip:proxy_port

For example
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://myusername:Password1@proxy.local:8080

Comment: But my password contains @, Like: P@ssword, What i do?

Comment: In terminal: $ set HTTPS_PROXY=http://myusername:Password1@proxy.local:8080   ?                                     Or in /etc/defaut/docker ?

Answer (score 1):

For docker on windows, follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#proxy-configuration) to configure the proxy variables:

In powershell perform the following for HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "http://username:password@proxy:port/", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Once the variables are set, restart the service with powershell:

```
Restart-Service docker
```

---

Edit: For Linux native installs of Docker using systemd, follow [these steps](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy) to configure your proxy:

> 1. Create a systemd drop-in directory for the docker service:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
```

> 2. Create a file called /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf that adds the HTTP_PROXY environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"
```

> Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server, create a file called /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/https-proxy.conf that adds the HTTPS_PROXY environment variable:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/"
```

> 3. If you have internal Docker registries that you need to contact without proxying you can specify them via the NO_PROXY environment variable:

```
[Service]    
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.somecorporation.com"
```

> Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server:

```
[Service]    
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/" "NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.somecorporation.com"
```

> 4. Flush changes:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

> 5. Restart Docker:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

> 6. Verify that the configuration has been loaded:

```
$ systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/
```

> Or, if you are behind an HTTPS proxy server:

```
$ systemctl show --property=Environment docker
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443/
```

---

For special characters in your password, you can [use unicode](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-export-variable-http_proxy-with-special-characters/) to encode the characters:

If your original password was: `F@o:o!B#ar$`

The unicode equivalent would be: `F%40o%3Ao%21B%23ar%24`

Comment: Thank you, but I use Linux Mint, and i try configure HTTPS_PROXY, in /etc/default/docker, and i did not sucess

Comment: @kaue The "Windows 7" part of the question is confusing me. For Linux, configure the proxy variables in your systemd settings, /etc/default is only used by some vendor specific docker installs, not by the upstream docker-ce: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy